# C# class similar to Java Desktop class

Tags: c#, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open file with associated application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174156/open-file-with-associated-application)

I want to open a file in it respective application, e.g. open function of windows.

Same thing can be done in java with the help of `Desktop` class where you pass the file name and the respective file is opened.

But no idea how to do in C#.

Comment: Nope! There isn't and this thread is not duplicate. Java's Desktop includes -  launching the user-default browser,mail client, registered application to open, edit or print a specified file.

Comment: @AVD, that may all be so, but the OP was specific about a particular feature and the ability to "open a file in it respective application" is in fact possible (and trivial) in C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("filename.doc");
```