# How to open file which saved on local directory/ folder in asp.net C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to open a file which is saved in my local directory folder in asp.net c#.
I have tried filestream like this:

```
path = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value.ToString(); // file path (D:\projects\Content\Media\xxxx.PDF )

if (IsPostBack)
{
    path = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value.ToString();

    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
    if (fileInfo.Exists)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your query? It's a bit confusion to understand.

Comment: similar post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354978/opening-a-text-file-on-the-local-system-from-an-asp-net-web-application][1]
hope this helps you

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354978/opening-a-text-file-on-the-local-system-from-an-asp-net-web-application

Comment: What is the problem? What happens when you try to open the file? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: The file is saved  at my local drive folder,and bound with treeview node. once i click that file name(node), wants to open that file.

Comment: @bhavikshah28   Thanks.Got hint by mentioned link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of your question you are trying open the file means you are trying to launch the file
If i am right use this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Your_PDF_File_Path");
```

Edit:Here is an easy option for displaying pdf file in html5.

```
<embed src="Your_File.pdf" width="800px" height="2100px">
```

Comment: Yes, without using dignostic.process.start want to open file in browser.
the file is saved in my local drive,and bound with treeview node. once i click that file name, wants to open file.

Comment: If you want to display pdf file in browser i would suggest looking at [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) or [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/)