# How to open file(Display), Which is stored in directory in c# when click on link button in gridview

Tags: c#-4.0

How to open file(Display), Which is stored in directory in c# when click on link button in gridview.

In my application i am storing documents in directory.

I am displaying those documents path in gridview, Now i want to open particular document in new window or radwindow when click on link button of particular row.

My Code is.

```
protected void ImgBtnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridViewRow clickedRow = ((ImageButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        Label lblID = (Label)clickedRow.FindControl("lblFileName");
        string strDoc_FileName = lblID.Text.ToString();
        filePath = lblID.Text.ToString();
        // code to open file here ? 
    }
    catch { }

}
```

here filePath is geting location of file. Now i want to open that file in radwindow..Thanks

Comment: Could you show some effort, show some code please.

Comment: protected void ImgBtnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridViewRow clickedRow = ((ImageButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            Label lblID = (Label)clickedRow.FindControl("lblFileName");
            string strDoc_FileName = lblID.Text.ToString();
            filePath = lblID.Text.ToString();
            
        }
        catch { }

    }         here filePath is geting location of file. Now i want to open that file in radwindow..Thanks..

Comment: add this to your question please...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174156/open-file-with-associated-application

Comment: Hi,Its not working.Thanks..