# User drags file onto my winforms executable file. Do I create some event listener?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was reading the Stack Overflow article from this link: [Open File Associated Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174156/open-file-with-associated-application), and I am having a further problem, which is, my windows forms application opens, but I don't see the content. What do I do in my application to ensure it handles opening a file from Windows Explorer? The user would drag a file onto my winforms exe.

In a WinForms app, you'd need to grab the command line args from `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` method. However, there is an important distinction when calling this method vs. the console application: The first element in the array contains the file name of the executing program. If the file name is not available, the first element is equal to String..::.Empty. The remaining elements contain any additional tokens entered on the command line. I found this code to store the args, but I don't know what event to actually implement to in my application. Found the following on an MSDN thread.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
  string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

  if (args.Length > 1)
  {
    string filePath = args[1]; //First arg is the running process

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
      string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);

      File.Copy(filePath, name + ".dat");

      //todo - delete input
    }
  }

  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: You can also change `Main` to: `static void Main(string[] args)`. In this case, the path of your executable is not there. If arguments have been passed in, the first is in `args[0]`. Always check `args.Length` before accessing it. Or, if you want to use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`, you can evaluate `args[0]` to see whether it contains the executable path and (if `args.Length > 1`) extract the other arguments.

Comment: Btw, I'ld add an fully qualified path to `name + ".dat"`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I follow. You have a WinForms app that you want to display content when it opens? If so then you'd handle Form.Load and put the code to display that content in the handler.

Comment: You can also add a constructor to Form1 that accepts a `string[]` argument, modifying your empty constructor in `public MyAppMainForm() : this(null) { }`. Then run `Form1()` if `args[]` is empty (or only contains the executable path) and `Form(args)` if not empty. So you can just test, in the Forms' constructor, if `args` is null. If it's not, extract the arguments and process them. What you choose to do depends on when/where you want to process the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The user would drag a file onto my winforms exe.

You need to perform a [Drag-and-Drop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-performing-a-drag-and-drop-operation-in-windows-forms) operation in the target control. Assuming it is `Form1`.

First, enable the `AllowDrop` property:

```cs
Form1.AllowDrop = true;
```

Handle the `DragEnter` event to validate the operation:

```cs
private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        var file = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))[0];

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            return;
        }

        //If you need to allow certain type of files:
        //if (Path.GetExtension(file).Equals(".srcExt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        //{
        //    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        //    return;
        //}
    }
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

Then, handle the `DragDrop` event:

```cs
private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
    {
        //according to your snippet:
        var srcFile = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))[0];
        //Another check is good, just in case:
        if (File.Exists(srcFile))
        {
            var destDir = @"The destination Directory";
            var destFile = string.Concat(
                Path.Combine(
                destDir,
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(srcFile)
                ),
                ".dat"
                );

            File.Move(srcFile, destFile);
        }
    }
}
```

As for the the `Main` part, I believe @Jimi has already covered that perfectly in his comments, so let's *steal* some from him to complete this post:

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if(args.Length > 0 && File.Exists(args[0]))
    {
        var srcFile = args[0];
        var destDir = @"The destination Directory";
        var destFile = string.Concat(
            Path.Combine(
            destDir,
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(srcFile)
            ),
            ".dat"
            );

        File.Move(srcFile, destFile);
    }

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());            
}
```

Good luck.