# Trying to launch PhotoViewer in C# but am getting conflicting information. What do I need to do?

Tags: c#, process.start, photoviewer

I am using C# in Windows 11.
PhotoViewer is the default app for AVI files on my PC. I am trying to launch PhotoViewer with an AVI file using the "Process.Start" method as follows:

```
MessageBox.Show(fn + " exists? " + File.Exists(fn));
Process.Start("@" + fn);
```

The MessageBox output is "d:\dscf0001.avi exists? true."
Process.Start throws a Win32Exception with the message "The system cannot find the file specified."
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is this "@" string for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open file with associated application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174156/open-file-with-associated-application)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have read from the internet, something like

```
Process.Start(@"D:\document.pdf");
```

They put the `@` at the beginning because the character `\` is the escape character and it needs to be disabled by @.

Refer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-string

In your case, you don't need it.

```
Process.Start(fn);
```

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you.