# How to open multiple files in notepad tabs c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to open multiple files at the same-time using file path.

Until now I was working on windows 10. So used below code

`Process prc = Process.Start(“notepad.exe”, path);`

Above opens multiple notepads which was fine in windows 10 for my requirement.

But after migrating to windows 11, I would like to open all those files in same window but different tabs like below.

[image: Tabs in Notepad]

Comment: Did you enable tabs in Notepad? Because the screenshot is probably not yours but rather [copied without attribution](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2023/01/19/tabs-in-notepad-begins-rolling-out-to-windows-insiders/). IMHO the decision whether and how to use tabs should be left up to Notepad. If Notepad wanted to use tabs, it could do so.

Comment: Yes I tried opening the same files from explorer. It is opening in tabs. But when I call it in code it is opening separate notepad windows

Comment: How about `Process.Start("start", path)`?

Comment: @Oliver: that certainly requires Notepad to be the default application for text files.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a temporary working method for now using below code. Please comment if there is better way.

```
ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo(file);
pi.Arguments = Path.GetFileName(file);
pi.UseShellExecute = true;
pi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
pi.FileName = file;
pi.Verb = "OPEN";
Process.Start(pi);
```

---

Only drawback is notepad needs to be default application to open the file.
Found above code in [Open file with associated application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174156/open-file-with-associated-application)

Comment: Why shouldn't this work if you use `notepad` instead of `file` as ProcessStartInfo?

Answer (score -5):

try notepad++

```
Process myProcess = new Process(); 
Process.Start("notepad++.exe", "\"c:\\file name for test.txt\"");
```